# Confusion using XCode 4.5 for iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5, base-sdk

I am very much confused between iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0 with XCode 4.5. It's not very clear if I want to support my new App on iOS 5.0 onwards, which functionality should I use and which are not to use. Basically Xcode 4.5 gives you all functionality like Container Views and Unwind Segues in storyboard (...and many more that I might not be aware) that are available only from iOS 6.0 and you wouldn't know until you run your app and it crashes! Could anyone please let me know any simple solution to this? Do I have to revert back to Xcode 4.4? I am setting deployment target to iOS 5.0 but I couldn't set Base SDK to iOS 5.0 as it doesn't appear in the list. See attached image. Thanks.

[image: BASE SDK]

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to support 5.0 or 5.1, you may want to go into Xcode Preferences -> Downloads and install the iOS 5.0 or 5.1 simulator.

Comment: I already downloaded simulators and also set architecture to armv7 only. Still I can't set the base SDK! Basically I want to use XCode 4.5 but don't want to see iOS 6.0 features only that breaks on iOS 5.0!

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then. When I run my code with the iOS 5.1 simulator or with an iOS 5.1 device, it runs like iOS 5.x, NOT iOS 6. The reason I know this right now is because when I try to run my app in iOS 6.0, I get some weird errors with QuickLook that I'm still trying to figure out....but it runs fine in 5.1 like it used to. All in Xcode 4.5.

Comment: What's your deployment target in the Summary tab set to? Mine still says 5.1

Comment: yah that might be running fine if you don't use any iOS 6.o features that are not supported on iOS 5! Is your base SDK set to iOS5.0 or 6.0?

Comment: I said in original question. It's iOS 5.0 :) I wasn't able to set deployment target to anything lower than iOS 6.0 until I downloaded and installed iOS5.0 and 5.1 simulators but that didn't solve my issue as I can still use iOS 6.0 features. I expect compilation errors or don't want to use features that are not supported on iOS 5.0.

Comment: One of the main differences between running on iOS 5 and iOS 6 devices with XCode 4.5 and iOS SDK 6.0 and deployment target 5.0 is the behavior of auto rotation as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS 6.0.  5.x devices do get the old rotation notifications, 6.0 devices don't, which in my mind is absurd since the deployment target is 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had this very same issue. I am using Xcode 4.5 to create a project targetted at iOS 5 so the project base SDK is iOS6.

I got around the issue by editing the `MainStoryBoard.storyboard` file and removed the `trigger="accessoryAction"` from the following line

**before:**

```
< segue destination="f1z-co-5vQ" kind="push" identifier="ShowTestPoints2" trigger="accessoryAction" id="KQV-Ht-eG9"/>
```

**after:**

```
< segue destination="f1z-co-5vQ" kind="push" identifier="ShowTestPoints2" id="KQV-Ht-eG9"/>
```